# How does a CNN work in detecting absence of features?

Tags: deep-learning, convolutional-neural-networks, computer-vision

I'm trying to understand how a CNN operates internally. Let's say I'm doing binary classification with 1 output neuron and a sigmoid to classify dog vs no dog. No dog meaning the image does not contain a dog.

So what features does a CNN learn for no dog? Do the convulutional filters just learn the features of dogs and predict no dog when they aren't detected? Or do they learn some arbitrary features present in the no dog images?

Basically, I'm trying to understand how CNNs work to detect "absence of features."